# Returning a values as object properties

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I have to write a function that takes in an array and returns an object with the first element of the array as the object's key and the last element of the array as the object's value.

Here is the challenge presented:

> Write a function 'transformFirstAndLast' that takes in an array, and returns an object with: 
>   1) the first element of the array as the object's key, and 
>   2) the last element of the array as that key's value.

Example input:

```
['Queen', 'Elizabeth', 'Of Hearts', 'Beyonce']
```

Function's return value (output):

```
{
  Queen : 'Beyonce'
}
```

Do not change the input array. Assume all elements in the input array will be of type 'string'.

Note that the input array may have a varying number of elements. Your code should flexibly accommodate that.

E.g. it should handle input like:

```
['Kevin', 'Bacon', 'Love', 'Hart', 'Costner', 'Spacey']
```

Function's return value (output):

```
{
  Kevin : 'Spacey'
}
```

Starter Code

```
function transformFirstAndLast(array) {
  // your code here
}
```

And here is my code

```
function transformFirstAndLast() {
  //Take in an array
  array = ['Queen', 'Elizabeth', 'Of Hearts', 'Beyonce'];
  //Return an object with:
  return {
//element 1     element 2
  stuckHere : array[array.length-1],
};
}
  //call function
  transformFirstAndLast();
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using computed property keys as described [here](http://www.benmvp.com/learning-es6-enhanced-object-literals/):

```js
function transformFirstAndLast(array) {
  return {[array[0]]: array[array.length - 1]};
}

console.log(transformFirstAndLast(['Queen', 'Elizabeth', 'Of Hearts', 'Beyonce']));
```

The object property key `[array[0]]` is computed from the first array element `array[0]`. Its value is the last array element `array[array.length - 1]`.

You should consider passing the `array` as an argument to the `transformFirstAndLast` function as done here to comply with the function signature provided by the challenge.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to explain this for me.

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```
function transformFirstAndLast() {
    //Take in an array
    array = ['Queen', 'Elizabeth', 'Of Hearts', 'Beyonce'];
    //Return an object with:
    var output = {};
    output[array[0]] = array[array.length-1];
    return output;
}

//call function
transformFirstAndLast();
```